# PostgreSQL group by on different columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table as the following:

| branch_id | parent_branch_id | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 3 |  | 8 |
| 4 | 3 | 3 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 |  | 6 |

I need to aggregate the table on branches of a father branch

| branch_id | sales |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 16 |
| 3 | 11 |
| 6 | 6 |

**What I have tried:**

I tried first separating the branches which have a parent branch and aggregating them on their parent_branch_id, then joining this aggregated table with the table of the parent only branches on t1.parent_branch_id=t2.branch_id and summing the resulting columns to get total sales.

I feel this, having to join tables, is costly and maybe there is a smarter way to do it with builtin PostgreSQL functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `join` for this:

```
select coalesce(parent_branch_id, branch_id) as branch_id, 
       sum(sales)
from t
group by coalesce(parent_branch_id, branch_id)
order by branch_id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=42698b8d570a5155e558d50e6e0dd5c2) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that we only need to consider two levels, parents and immediate children, we can try a self join approach here:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(t1.parent_branch_id, t1.branch_id) AS branch_id,
       SUM(t1.sales) AS sales
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t2.branch_id = t1.parent_branch_id
GROUP BY
    COALESCE(t1.parent_branch_id, t1.branch_id);
```